# Making a list out of comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison, ranking

For the past few days i've been looking into Javascript and how to make list out of comparison, i found something about arrays, and while i knew that this is what i need, I couldn't understand how it exactly worked with my very little knowledge about Javascript.

I want to make a list, say we have 5 items (let's take a, b, c, d, e as examples) and you're asked to compare one to another (do u like "a" or "d"?) and each time you choose an item it gets a point and it keeps asking you until all the comparisons are made with each item, then a list is made out of those comparisons and the items with the most points are ranked first.

if there is an article, a video, a code that i can analyze, anything would help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of how you could approach it.

So you could have the following setup:

```
const items = ["a", "b", "c", "d", ...and so on]
const pointsRecord = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, ...and so on}
```

With these two pieces you can build pairs to compare, and keep track of the points of each item.

From your description it sounds like you want to compare every item with every other item on the list. You will probably have to loop through the list twice and build a comparison pair that you can output, or render on the screen.

You could write a function to build comparison pairs to look something like this:

```
const comparisonPairs = [
    [ "a", "b" ],
    [ "a", "c" ],
    [ "a", "d" ],
    [ "b", "c" ],
    ...and so on
]
```

With something like this you could iterate through comparisonPairs, render the pair on the screen or output to the terminal. Then take the input, and update the pointsRecord object. Something like:

```
pointsRecord = {
   ...pointsRecord, // copy over all the data from the original point record
   [selectedItem]: pointsRecord[selectedItem] + 1 // increment the points of the selected item
}
```

After updating pointsRecord you could move on to the next pair.

To sort them at the end you would just have to run a sort function on the items. Something like:

```
const sortedItems = items.slice().sort((a, b) => pointsRecord[b] - pointsRecord[a]);
```

Adding the .slice() creates a new array so you don't alter the original typically this is good practice but you may want to sort the original in place depending on your use case.

This is just one approach. For sure you want to think about how you want to organize the data, which it sounds like you are already doing so you are on the right track. As you are working through this if you find that it's getting messy, updating things, and keeping track of the data, that may be a good sign to re-asses and re-think if there is a better way to store the information.

Comment: i'll try  doing that, thank u so much for the help, but why would i need to go over the same list twice ?
and sorry if i wasn't clear enough, but the base idea exists already in sorta.app 
maybe that will help you understand what i want to achieve

Comment: Didn't know about sorta.app, really cool! Yea even they are probably going through the list twice potentially behind the scenes. The reason you may have to do this is to build your pairs. For example, if you have a list [a, b, c], an example of pairs could be [[a, b], [a, c], [b, c]]. So building this may require you to loop through the list for every element in the list.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply!
is there a place where i can find this in-depth, like a step by step thing or what do u recommend me to look for in order to achieve this, i'm planning to learn JS but i want to get this done before learning it, sounds illogical i know but i feel like i can make it work

Comment: I don't think there is a tutorial out there to build exactly this, however their might be, you can google around. If you don't find an exact match, you can sort of aggregate a bunch that could be helpful. Take bits and pieces from each one. Learning by building is one of the best ways to learn! So your on track to learn JS. Good luck with the project!

Comment: getting close to it!! thanks for helping, appreciate it